# Attempting to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, com-interop, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have written a Windows Service using C# which uses the lotus domino `interop` dll to communicate with lotus notes server and sends emails. It was working fine few months ago.
When I rebuilt the solution, I received the following error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

```
_notesDataBase = _notesSession.GetDatabase(serverName, sMailFile, false);
```

Error occurs in the line specified above.

Additional info: I recently changed my lotus notes server password for my mail box.As I figured out that might be problem in ID file of lotus notes?

Comment: Out of sheer morbid curiosity - *why* did you go through the bother of making a screenshot, rather than copy-pasting your code?

Comment: I am connected to a remote machine.It would be lot simpler if you take screenshot.

Comment: I took the liberty of typing it out for you.

Comment: Can you capture and post the full stacktrace for this error?

Comment: Haha 3 Years untill the first reply came :D

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue!
When `Session.GetDatabase()` get called the exception gets thrown in one of it's sub Threads, making it nearly impossible to findout what is actually causing the Problem.

Here is what helped me:

1. Deinstalling Lotus Notes
2. Backing up my local Database files
   This [website](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/de/SSKTWP_8.5.3/com.ibm.notes85.client.doc/app_important_files_to_backup_r.html) should give you a good overview on what might be important to keep. It is in german but it should help never the less.
3. Deleting Registry entries
   I deleted  entries under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.
   Just look for `Software` and you should find IBM there.
   Some more IBM stuff was hidden in `HKEY-LOCAL-MACHINE --> SOFTWARE --> Wow6432Node`.
4. Reinstalling Lotus Notes

This wrapped up the problem for me nice and neatly.
The real source of the bug is yet to be discoverd...

---

EDIT:
It's enough to run the installer and select `repair`.